# Importing googletest into gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: c++, android-studio, gradle, android-ndk, googletest

I was hoping if anyone could help me figure out how to setup googletest to work from inside Android Studio. I want to run my C++ unit tests from within the same IDE as I am writing them in. I am aware that googletest is already supplied with the ndk, I just can't seem to integrate it into my project.

I found a couple of blogs and stackoverflow topics, and even the googletest documentation all point to the following solution (Android.mk):

```
   TARGET_ARCH_ABI := armeabi-v7a
   LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := foo
   FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/*.cpp)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
   include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)

   include $(CLEAR_VARS)
   LOCAL_MODULE := foo_unittest
   FILE_LIST := $(wildcard $(LOCAL_PATH)/gtest/*.cpp)
   LOCAL_SRC_FILES := $(FILE_LIST:$(LOCAL_PATH)/%=%)
   LOCAL_SHARED_LIBRARIES := foo
   LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := googletest_main
   include $(BUILD_EXECUTABLE)

   $(call import-module,third_party/googletest)
```

However, there is no Android.mk file. As I've understood it, gradle now generates the Android.mk behind the scene. All we are left with is the build.gradle file. Importing the library I might be able to do, but importing the project that generates that library is not so apparent to me.

If anyone could point me to a project that already does this, or give me a few tips on how to achieve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Cheers